# jhipster 5.0.1 and kafka error: A list of partitions must be provided, no way to start it

Tags: apache-kafka, jhipster

I have created a minimal jhipster application with 5.0.1 generator with kafka [1](https://github.com/flefevre/jhipster5kafka): 3 commits

- application generartion with jhipster genrator
- adding a book author datamodel jdl
- adding the kafka elements

I have followed the tutorial here [2](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-kafka/)

nevertheless the application is not able to start on a CentOS 7.5 environment

starting kafka:
`docker-compose -f src/main/docker/kafka.yml up -d`

starting my app
`./mvnw`

```
2018-06-25 10:56:40.883  WARN 15375 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : The number of expected partitions was: 1, but 0 has been found instead.There will be 1 idle consumers
2018-06-25 10:56:40.886 ERROR 15375 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create consumer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while starting consumer: 
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:326)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:77)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:129)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindConsumer(BindingService.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:234)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:52)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:47)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:31)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:885)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.flfmitlab.jhipster5kafka.Jhipster5KafkaApp.main(Jhipster5KafkaApp.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A list of partitions must be provided
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:354)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:126)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:279)
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2018-06-25 10:56:41.285  INFO 15375 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.jhipster5kafka.Jhipster5KafkaApp     : Started Jhipster5KafkaApp in 14.489 seconds (JVM running for 14.981)
2018-06-25 10:56:41.304  INFO 15375 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.jhipster5kafka.Jhipster5KafkaApp     : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'jhipster5kafka' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080
    External:   http://127.0.0.1:8080
    Profile(s):     [dev, swagger]
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-06-25 10:57:10.861 ERROR 15375 --- [ad | producer-3] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{84, 101, 115, 116, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 74, 72, 105, 1...' to topic topic-jhipster:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 31 record(s) for topic-jhipster-0: 30077 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

2018-06-25 10:57:10.864 ERROR 15375 --- [ad | producer-3] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{84, 101, 115, 116, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 74, 72, 105, 1...' to topic topic-jhipster:
```

Some details on my configuration

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
```

And for kafka configuration

```
spring:
cloud:
    stream:
        bindings:
        messageChannel:
            destination: greetings
            content-type: application/json
        subscribableChannel:
            destination: greetings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a case of not shutting down kafka/zookeeper properly . If kafka process/container is killed or crashes, rather than stopped, it doesn't close zookeeper connection correctly.

Try stopping kafka Docker gracefully with `docker stop <container_id>`, before stopping zookeeper. Then try to start kafka again with docker-compose.

Comment: It seems to solve a first error, but I am not able still to get a consummer message...

2018-06-25 15:01:04.152 ERROR 1137 --- [ad | producer-3] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{84, 101, 115, 116, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 74, 72, 105, 1...' to topic topic-jhipster:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 31 record(s) for topic-jhipster-0: 30065 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Comment: You were right! I have deleted all docker images,, introduce a "        depends_on:
            - "zookeeper"" on the docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with kafka.
If you are using docker for containerization, then stop kafka, remove kafka and start kafka container.
Once check the IP address set for kafka.